# Using nested EL for dynamically reading numbered header values does not work any more

Tags: apache-camel

As a minimal example, consider an exchange with a few header values like this:

- header.test0
- header.test1
- header.test2
- ...

I realise that numbered header fields like this are not ideal, but this is not something I can change.

In the past (up to Camel 2.17) I was able to loop over these values like this (XML DSL):

```
<loop>
   <simple>${header.myCounter}</simple>
   <log message="${header.test${header.CamelLoopIndex}}"/>
</loop>
```

However, since upgrading to Camel 2.21 this results in the following error:
`org.apache.camel.language.simple.types.SimpleIllegalSyntaxException: expected symbol functionEnd but was eol at location 16   test${header`

The [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_fuse/7.5/html/apache_camel_development_guide/simple) states that simple expressions can still be nested, so I am unsure why it stopped working, and how I can fix this. I suppose that my issue is caused by the fact that I am combining static text with dynamic values, whereas existing examples always take the complete dynamic value as name.

So my question is, what is the correct way for reading the values of header.test0, header.test1, ... in a loop dynamically?

Comment: Would you mind posting the whole route configuration? Perhaps we can find a way out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that has similar issues:

The issue is not the nested expressions. The issue is that a SimpleIllegalSyntaxException will be thrown if you're using a nested expression (like in the example) AND when the header field does not exist. In older versions of Camel a non-existing header field would just evaluate to "null". In more recent version an exception is thrown.

Assuming the example above, an exception will be thrown if you loop from 0 to 5, and if header.test5 doesn't exist (for instance).

The null-safe "?." doesn't help here. The "solution" is to use a [try/catch](https://people.apache.org/~dkulp/camel/try-catch-finally.html) (yes, you can do that in XML DSL) and to do the appropriate thing in the "catch" part if the header value does not exist. It's clumsy, but it allows you to replicate the original behaviour of your routes in newer Camel versions.